# How to use Bing Speech for C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, speech-recognition, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to get Bing Speech followed this link:

**www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api** it says: *"Show Quota is temporarily unavailable. We are working hard to bring an improved version back in the middle of October."* and I can't see it in the list, there is only Bing Search.

I found this **www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/overview** I've pressed Get started for free and got two keys.

Now I have to find basic code to use it. I found this: **www.github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows**, Actually I'm just moved my code from Windows Form Application to WPF with same interface and it is works without any special changes, but fact is I'm new with WPF so not sure what I have to use to get needed output.

Maybe I have to follow instruction just by this: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStartedCSharpWin10

Comment: I don't understand your question. But it seems that you want to use Bing Speech in C#. There is an example included in the SDK. It is using WPF. 
Here is the link:
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/GetStarted/GetStartedCSharpDesktop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're interested in a C# sample, maybe this can help: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-SpeechToText. It is a sample speech-to-text bot, which uses the Bing Speech API. The bot reads the audio file that the user uploaded, and then converts it into text. Obviously, you can leverage the same code to run speech-to-text for non-bot applications.